# What does bitwise & 0x3FF do?

Tags: java, primitive-types

Can someone explain the following line of code? Particularly, I don't get what `(short) x & 0x3FF` does?

```
int num = ... //some number.
return (short) num & 0x3FF;
```

Comment: It throws out all but the bottom 10 bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It zeros out the top bits of the number, such that the result is always between 0 and 1023. It's essentially the same thing as modulo(num, 1024) (for positive values of num).

Without seeing a broader context it's impossible to know *why* this is here, but that's what it does.

Answer (score 8):

`0x3FF` is the number `1111111111` in binary, which means that the bitwize AND with it would give you the last 10 bits of `num`.

Answer (score 3):

Converting hex to binary, `0x3FF == 0b1111111111`.

The `&` performs bitwise AND, so it will only keep the low bits if they were set to be on.
This guarantees that the answer is no larger than 0x3FF == 1023, so the answer is saved into a `short`, since we know it'll fit in one.

Answer (score 1):

The java operator `&` is a "bitwise AND", meaning each bit of the two operands is ANDed together, leaving a `1` if *both* corresponding bits are `1`.

`0x3ff` is binary `1111111111`, so ANDing with that will mask all but the lowest ten bits.

The cast to `short` (a 16-bit number format) has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

It retains only the right-most 10 bits.